# Any way to specify an explicit viewport?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I need to geocode some locations (done), then draw a custom overlay on top of a map (client orders)... but to do that, I need to know exactly what the viewport area is. The only way I can see to do that is to specify in the static maps query exactly what the bounds are... but it doesn't seem like it's possible. Is there something in the Static Maps API that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set the bounds of the map, except like this:

i.e.) I specify the bounds that contains Hokkaido(Japan)

[image]

I set the path that opacity is zero and line weight is zero.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=256x256&sensor=false&path=color:0xff00000000|weight:0|41.3780,139.3555|45.1870,146.9415

[image]

As you may know, it's not exactly the viewport I specified.

Comment: In that case, when specifying a set of locations to keep visible and letting the viewport size automatically, is the buffer space on each side of the provided locations list constant? Like, is the farthest-left location *always* 12.5% of the image width inside the border? (Random buffer used as example)

Comment: I don't think so. The document doesn't mention it.

Comment: Bit of experimentation confirms that no, the padding is not at all constant. However, in drawing a box at known coordinates, it shouldn't be that difficult to scan the image and interpolate my data points onto it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just remember.
I tried the similar purpose and solved this one.
You always know the center position, zoom, and the size of the map.
Since Google uses Mercator projection (more correctly they use "EPSG:900913" projection), you can calculate the exactly viewport from these information in server side.

I created by php though, I lost my code.

Try it.